# Using input vector field in QGIS python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have created a QGIS Graphic Model using built-in Graphic Modeler. My model is supposed ask the user for an input layer, an overlay layer, and fields from the overlay layer.

The model then should calculate the area-weighted average of those fields for each feature in the input layer. The result will be an input layer with extra fields for each area-weighted average.

[image]

I have realized that the field input can't be used in graphic modeller and I have to turn it into a python script to perform this task. I am adding the script here. What I am having trouble is with how to use the input from the user in my field calculations and field names.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterField
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class FutureLuHsg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('luhsgexisting', 'LU HSG', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('parcels', 'Parcels', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('fieldtoaverage1', 'Field to Average', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Numeric, parentLayerParameterName='luhsgexisting', allowMultiple=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Joined', 'Joined', optional=True, type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Final', 'Final', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Stats', 'Stats', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(6, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Field calculator
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'FID_Parcels',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 1,
            'FORMULA': '$id',
            'INPUT': parameters['parcels'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Intersection
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': None,
            'OVERLAY': parameters['luhsgexisting'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS': parameters['fieldtoaverage1'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Intersection'] = processing.run('native:intersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator 2
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'Field1*Area',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 2,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': ' \"fieldtoaverage\"  *  $area',
            'INPUT': outputs['Intersection']['OUTPUT'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator2'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Statistics by categories
        alg_params = {
            'CATEGORIES_FIELD_NAME': 'FID_Parcels',
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculator2']['OUTPUT'],
            'VALUES_FIELD_NAME': 'Field1*Area',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Stats']
        }
        outputs['StatisticsByCategories'] = processing.run('qgis:statisticsbycategories', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Stats'] = outputs['StatisticsByCategories']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Join attributes by field value
        alg_params = {
            'DISCARD_NONMATCHING': False,
            'FIELD': 'FID_Parcels',
            'FIELDS_TO_COPY': 'SUM',
            'FIELD_2': 'FID_Parcels',
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'INPUT_2': outputs['StatisticsByCategories']['OUTPUT'],
            'METHOD': 1,
            'PREFIX': 'Stats_',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Joined']
        }
        outputs['JoinAttributesByFieldValue'] = processing.run('native:joinattributestable', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Joined'] = outputs['JoinAttributesByFieldValue']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator 3
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'Field1_Weighted',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': ' \"Statssum\" / $area',
            'INPUT': outputs['JoinAttributesByFieldValue']['OUTPUT'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Final']
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculator3'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Final'] = outputs['FieldCalculator3']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Future LU HSG'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Future LU HSG'

    def group(self):
        return 'QGIS Tools'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'QGIS Tools'

    def createInstance(self):
        return FutureLuHsg()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say: "What I am having trouble is with how to use the input from the user in my field calculations and field names".

Could you explain more about the trouble you are experiencing?

### About processing parameter / user input

You access the user input using `parameters[]` and `output[]`.
That is fine, but you can also access parameters as described in the QGIS [user manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/).
Have a look at [Writing new Processing algorithms as Python scripts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).

Some examples from the documentation.
To get a feature source:

```
    input_featuresource = self.parameterAsSource(parameters,
                                                 'INPUT',
                                                 context)
```

To get a double:

```
    doublepar = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, 'BUFFERDIST',
                                        context)
```

I guess you can see the pattern :-).
What you do here is to assign the values of your input parameters to variables for using them in your script.
Place these early in your `ProcessAlgorithm` method (before you need them for your calculations).

### Regarding your specific question

To access the input vector field you can use
parameters['fieldtoaverage1']. Some examples from your code:

```
 'FIELD_NAME': parameters['fieldtoaverage1'] + '*Area',

 'FORMULA': parameters['fieldtoaverage1'] + ' * $area',
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to read the documentation but I am unable to find the answer to this. How can I access the fieldtoaverage1 value in the Field Calculator 2 formula line? Any help specific to this will be appreciated

Comment: I realized that my question is not specific enough. I have posted a new question with fewer details and being more specific. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352823/accessing-vector-field-parameter-value-inside-python-script

I will delete this question once you reply there. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I have provided an answer to the new question. The answer includes code (modification of code in your question).